# parsleyJs validation on form not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation, parsley.js

I am using parsley.js for form validation. I read through the documentation on the website and followed their examples, but it does not seem to work as expected.

Here's the test file I created:

```
    <doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parsley</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src ="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="parsley.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="parsley.css">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <h2>Parsley.js Form Validation</h2>

                    <form id="testForm" data-parsley-validate>
                        <label>Name</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="name" data-required="true">

                        <br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `data-parsley-required` or directly `required` in your DOM.

Here are all the built-in validators: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators

Best

Comment: Required will trigger the html5 validation api which is not what I need.

Comment: If putting `required` trigger html5 validation, that means that Parsley is not loaded or that js is broken. Please look your console to see what happens.

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations. StackOverflow was my last hope. Could you possibly help with a jsfiddle?. The console did not log any errors.

Answer (score 0):

javascript file import should be in following order.

```
JQuery.js
Parsley.js
Common.js
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/parsley.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/common.js}"></script>
```

If it's not like this, some component can't be known and it'll not working.I know it is a bit late, but I hope it can help someone.